# trouble loading external JSON file in python

Tags: python, json

I'm a beginner to python,  I have an external JSON file looks like this

```
[
{
    "Name1": "Schule an der Admiralstraße",
    "Strasse": "Winterstr. 20",
    "PLZ": 28215,
    "Ort": "Bremen",
    "Schulnummer": "002"
},
{
    "Name1": "Schule am Alten Postweg",
    "Strasse": "Alter Postweg 302",
    "PLZ": 28207,
    "Ort": "Bremen",
    "Schulnummer": "003"
},
{
    "Name1": "Schule Am Mönchshof",
    "Strasse": "Hindenburgstr. 33 A",
    "PLZ": 28717,
    "Ort": "Bremen",
    "Schulnummer": "005"
},
{
    "Name1": "Schule An der Gete",
    "Strasse": "An der Gete 103",
    "PLZ": 28211,
    "Ort": "Bremen",
    "Schulnummer": "006"
},
{
    "Name1": "Schule an der Alfred-Faust-Straße",
    "Strasse": "Alfred-Faust-Str. 34",
    "PLZ": 28277,
    "Ort": "Bremen",
    "Schulnummer": "007"
}
]
```

I'm trying to load it with this code

```
import json
jsonfile = 'pathtomyfile'
with open(jsonfile) as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
```

but I get the error:  *ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded*
  I guess my JSON isn't valid somehow or i'm not handling the German characters correctly.  I just can't figure it out.

Comment: The JSON you posted is valid, but not necessarily exactly what is in your file. What encoding was used for the file?

Comment: It works fine for me...

Comment: What version of Python are you using? You may need to use `codecs.open()` and specify the proper `encoding` keyword argument.

Comment: I'm using version 2.7.5. of python.  I just pasted the JSON into notepad, so I assume it is in unicode.

Comment: So, I saved my JSON as utf-8 in another plain text editor (not Notepad) and it worked!   Though i don't really understand why.  Thanks for the comments above though, they helped me get there.